# Cassandra C/C++ API cass_statement_bind_timestamp

Tags: c++, api, cassandra

cass_statement_bind_timestamp doesn't appear to exist.

From [this example](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/1.0/examples/prepared/prepared.c), there are multiple API calls available to bind various data types to a CassStatement:

```
cass_statement_bind_string(statement, 0, cass_string_init(key));
cass_statement_bind_bool(statement, 1, basic->bln);
cass_statement_bind_float(statement, 2, basic->flt);
cass_statement_bind_double(statement, 3, basic->dbl);
cass_statement_bind_int32(statement, 4, basic->i32);
cass_statement_bind_int64(statement, 5, basic->i64);
```

But there doesn't appear to be a corresponding API call for binding a timestamp data type.  Can I just bind these as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [cass_statement_bind_int64](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/blob/9b0c5c/include/cassandra.h#L847-L859). From the documentation:

> Binds a "bigint", "counter" or "timestamp" to a query or bound statement at the specified index.